# When the kernel of a quotient of a locally free sheaf is locally free

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Can you please help me understand the following. Let $A$ be a locally free sheaf on a ringed space (e.g nice scheme) and $B$ some coherent sheaf with a surjection from $A$. Assuming that the homological dimension of $B$ is less or equal to $1$, (that is, for $i\geq2$ the groups $H^i(X,B)$ are equal to zero) then the kernel of the surjection $A\to B\to 0$ is also locally free.

Comment: Homological dimension less than or equal to one does not mean what you say. It is a local assumption and not global. For example, your base $X$ could be an affine variety, then $H^i(X,B)=0$ for $i>0$ and any $B$, not necessarily one of homological dimension less than or equal to one.

Comment: What does homological dimension mean? I could not find a reference. Infact $X$ will probably be projective in my context. Thank you!

Comment: Search for projective dimension of a module. These words are used interchangeably.  As I said, projective variety or affine makes little difference for this, since the notion is local.

Comment: Ok, so it is basically saying the same thing, thanks!